# Is it possible that we construct sequence of polynominals the limit of which is $z^i$ on unit disc excluding $(-1,0]$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $D$ it is a unit disk excluding $(-1,0]$ is it possible to construct a sequence of polynomials such that $\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{n}(z)= z^i$ for $z$ in D?

I have to use Runge theorem this I know and we know that if a rational has pole at infinity then it’s a polynomial. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is actually a past exam problem and I’m studying for an exam. I’m not looking for a solution but for hints. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Uutahyo.

Comment: Do you really mean $(-1,0]$ for the "unit disk"?  Oh, I see the "excluding" now.  The question is unclear.

Comment: Im sorry i corrected it , it’s \ (-1,0], the i as in imaginary unit i^2=-1